# Play framework error: not found: value message

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I have a route, controller and view defined. When I do a get request for the home directory, which is "/", I am getting the error `not found: value message`. `index.scala.html:2`.

routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index(message: String, name: String)    

GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count    

GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

index.scala.html:

```
@(name: String)
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Sparta") {

     @welcome(message, style = "java") 

}
```

HomeController.java:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.*;

import views.html.*;

import java.util.Date;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    public String name;
    public String message;


    public Result index(String name, String message) {
        name = "TEST NAME";
        message = "Test message";
        return ok(name, "message: " + message);
    }

}
```

**Why is the error telling me I have not defined a value for `message`?**

Answer (score 0):

Your route and index method in the controller is not correct. If you are sending any parameters to the server, they come into the picture. Your URL does look like you are sending some parameter with it, so please remove parameters for the index method.

```
public Result index() {
    name = "TEST NAME";
    message = "Test message";
    return ok(name, "message: " + message);
}
```